# Which Membership Provider implements users stored in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

Having a code-blind moment.

ASP.NET 4.0.

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="DataViewer" loginUrl="login.aspx">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <user name="devuser" password="test" />
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

and a login control:

```
  <asp:Login ID="login" runat="server" />
```

If I enter a username and password, and click Login, it hangs.

If I break, I can see in the call stack that `login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider()` is in the middle of calling `SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser()`. There is no database defined or involved in this project at all, and I haven't specified that SqlMembershipProvider should be used.

So my question is, what membership provider should I use to get ASP.NET to use the usernames and passwords in the `<credentials>` element of `web.config`?

Comment: may be because default Membership provider is the AspNetSqlProvider which uses a SQL Server database as its user store.

Comment: I'm hoping this is a temporary solution. It will become very difficult to maintain credentials in web.config as each change will restart the web application.

Comment: Of course. However it's suitable for the scenario at hand. I need to provide trivial protection to a simple application for a single user (ever) whose password will never change. A solution with greater dependencies is not appropriate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm amazed that considering how the framework designers went to the trouble of defining a `<credentials />` element that they didn't implement any code to consume it.

I found a sort-of-working implementation of this [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2005/07/27/asp-net-membershipprovider-for-web-config/) which I have fixed up and included below. All other members of `MembershipProvider` throw `NotImplementedException`.

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;

public class WebConfigMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private FormsAuthenticationUserCollection _users = null;
    private FormsAuthPasswordFormat _passwordFormat;

    public override void Initialize(string name,
      System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        base.Initialize(name, config);
        _passwordFormat = getPasswordFormat();
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = getUsers()[username];
        if (user == null) return false;

        if (_passwordFormat == FormsAuthPasswordFormat.Clear)
        {
            if (user.Password == password)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (user.Password == FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password,
                _passwordFormat.ToString()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected FormsAuthenticationUserCollection getUsers()
    {
        if (_users == null)
        {
            AuthenticationSection section = getAuthenticationSection();
            FormsAuthenticationCredentials creds = section.Forms.Credentials;
            _users = section.Forms.Credentials.Users;
        }
        return _users;
    }

    protected AuthenticationSection getAuthenticationSection()
    {
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        return (AuthenticationSection)config.GetSection("system.web/authentication");
    }

    protected FormsAuthPasswordFormat getPasswordFormat()
    {
        return getAuthenticationSection().Forms.Credentials.PasswordFormat;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to use the deprecated method FormsAuthentication.Authenticate. Thanks for putting the class here.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need to write your own provider for this. It should be relatively straightforward to take the sample `ReadOnlyXmlMembershipProvider` in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479021.aspx#aspnetprovmodvb_prt1_topic5) and change it to read users and credentials from `web.config`, instead of an external XML file.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you have tried but....

The [FormsAuthentication.Authenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx) is in charge to do that for you (although it is deprecated now because the recommended behavior is to use the Membership object)

From MSDN:

> The Authenticate method verifies user credentials that are stored in the credentials section of the application configuration file. Alternatively, you can use ASP.NET membership to store user credentials and call the ValidateUser to verify the credentials.

You can also remove the membership providers (because even when you do not declare them on your web.config, they are inherited from the machine.config file)

```
  <membership>
    <providers>
      <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
    </providers>
  </membership>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using this method. I hope it helps. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.onauthenticate.aspx